# Google Cloud SDK failed to install on Windows 10, no details

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, windows-10, google-cloud-sdk

[image: GDS failed to install on Windows 10, giving me no details why]

I tried to install with only this user, for all users, includint tab for beta commands, or without it. It failes each time with giving me no details why

Comment: Please try installing [Cloud SDK version 151.0.1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) that has just been released and let me know if it resolves your issue.